# Addresses, reinterpret_cast and multiple inheritance

Tags: c++, pointers, multiple-inheritance, reinterpret-cast

Can anybody explain the behaviour of the following code?

1. Why do we have `b = 3` in the first case, i.e. `b2 == &d` is true?
2. Why is it ok in Case 2? I have printed the addresses of `b2` and `d`, and they are different.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    A() : m_i(0) { }

protected:
    int m_i;
};

class B
{
public:
    B() : m_d(0.0) { }

protected:
    double m_d;
};

class C
    : public A
    , public B
{
public:
    C() : m_c('a') { }

private:
    char m_c;
};

int main()
{
    C d;
    B *b2 = &d;

    cout << &d << endl;
    cout << b2 << endl;

    const int b = (b2 == &d) ? 3 : 4; ///Case1: b = 3;
    const int c = (reinterpret_cast<char*>(b2) == reinterpret_cast<char*>(&d)) ? 3 : 4; //Case 2:  c = 4;

    std::cout  << b << c << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 , just because this is a good example and illustrates the effects of multiple inheritance on pointers quite well

Comment: +1 likewise. great example, especially with no virtual's in there to truly send people through the ringer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

d is of type C. When you convert a pointer to C to a pointer to B, it is adjusted so that it points to the B subobject of C (such ajustement is needed in general with multiple inheritence, if none was needed for B, there would be one for A as C inherit from both A and B).  Thus at the assignation and comparison time, the adjustment is done.

At the two other times, &d is converted to either void* (implicitly) or char* (with a reinterpret_cast) and no adjustment is done (you asked explicitly for no adjustment with the reinterpret_cast and there is no reason to do an adjustment when converting to void*, it would just complicate the round trip for no good reason, you'd again have an similar result for A) so the representation is different.

BTW, if you had used `reinterpret_cast<B*>(&d)`, no adjustment would have been made again, but using the result as a B* would have lead rapidly to problems.

Answer (score 3):

In case 1, the comparison automatically casts the C pointer to a B pointer. In this case, this means that the actual address changes, since you use multiple inheritance and B is second in your list of base-classes. To be more specific, the pointer has to be offset by (at least) sizeof(A). In the second case, however, no such automatic conversion is performed, so the "A prefix" makes the two pointers unequal.

Comment: There is no such thing as an "automatic cast". A cast is an explicit conversion, it exists in the source code.

Comment: What do you mean by that? Clearly there's an upcast in case 1, but it is not explicit.

Comment: A cast that is not explicit is simply not a cast. A cast can be C-style, functional style or new style: `(T)x`, `T(x)`, `static_cast<T>(x)`...

Comment: You have any references for that claim? See http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/224493/what-is-casting-supposed-to-mean - "Some casts are applied implicitly, and in some of those the compiler will issue a warning." - an upCAST is clearly the former

Comment: It's the *definition* of a cast. It's a grammatical construct. The word you're looking for is **conversion**.